# What is a proper way to write data to a file?

Tags: python

Im trying to write some data to a file but I have some problems with the path Im using.

This is my code:

```
my_path = r'c:\data\XYM\Desktop\MyFolder 7-sep'

with open(my_path + '\\' + 'Vehicles_MM' + '\\' + name_vehicile + '-AB.txt', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerow(data)
    for vehicle_loc_list in vehicle_loc_dict.values():
        for record_group in group_records(vehicle_loc_list):
            writer.writerow(output_record(record_group))
```

This is the error I receive:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\data\\XYM\\Desktop\\MyFolder 7-sep\\Vehicles_MM\\20200907-AB.txt'
```

Comment: If the `Vehicles_MM` directory doesn't exist, you have to create it before you can create new files there.

Comment: @tripleee `Vehicles_MM` is a string, not a directory

Comment: Either you misunderstand my comment, or you misunderstand your own code. `open(my_path + '\\' + 'Vehicles_MM' + '\\' + name_vehicile + '-AB.txt', 'w')` is clearly trying to create a file in a a subdirectory of `my_path` whose name is `Vehicles_MM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on revelations in comments, the problem is that you are trying to write to a subdirectory `c:\data\XYM\Desktop\MyFolder 7-sep\Vehicle_MM\` which doesn't exist, and which actually you don't want to write into.

The fix is to remove the directory separator `\\`; maybe use a different separator instead. For example,

```py
with open(my_path + '\\' + 'Vehicles_MM-' + name_vehicile + '-AB.txt', 'w') as output:
```

If you did want to write to this subdirectory, you have to make sure it exists before you attempt to open a file inside it.

```py
os.makedirs(my_path + '\\' + 'Vehicles_MM', exist_ok=True)
with open(...
```

The same thing is somewhat more readable with `pathlib.Path`;

```py
from pathlib import Path

my_path = Path(r'c:\data\XYM\Desktop\MyFolder 7-sep')
vehicles_mm = my_path / 'Vehicles_MM'
vehicles_mm.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
filename = vehicles_m / name_vehicile + '-AB.txt'
with filename.open('w') as output:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the builtins to work with paths. Either `os.path` or `pathlib.Path`

```py
# with os.path:
import os.path as p
filename = p.join(my_path, "Vehicles_MM", name_vehicle + "-AB.txt")
assert p.exists(p.dirname(filename))

# with pathlib.Path:
from pathlib import Path
my_path = Path("c:\data\XYM\Desktop\MyFolder 7-sep")
filename = my_path.joinpath("Vehicles_MM", name_vehicle + "-AB.txt")
assert filename.parent.exists()
```

Comment: @qmuees, this has nothing to do with writing. Am I right?

Comment: nop, it has to do with the way paths are formatted and the fact that python will not create the directory if it was not found on the filesystem

Comment: Shouldnt the `w` automatically create a file if that file does not exist?

Comment: Yes but not the parent folder

Comment: My point is: Your path is probably formatted incorrectly. The error is telling you that the folder was not found. I assume that the folder exists but it is not formatted correctly. If the folder does not exist, then you have to create it.